# Visualizar la ñ y tildes en Sublime Text 3

Tags: mysql, sql, sublimetext3

Deseo visualizar la ñ y los caracteres especiales desde el **Build** de Sublime Text 3. Estoy corriendo script de MySQL desde este IDE pero obtengo este símbolo en caracteres especiales �, ejemplo: v�lido. Encontré la siguiente configuración en Sublime pero solo para Ubuntu:
https://gist.github.com/multiarts/6b916a5fe017ef2744ed

Cabe mencionar que cuando consulto una tabla en Workbench puedo visualizar los caracteres sin ningún problema, por lo que descartaría aplicar la codificación utf8 en la tabla.

Agradeceré cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 2):

Cuándo guardes codifícalo en utf-8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]